# Blender 2.8 alt f (focus on object) not working

Tags: 3d-view

in blender 2.79 shortcut alt f which navigates your view to the selected area doesn't work in blender 2.8 has the shortcut been changed or removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.79, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> focussed on the *mouse position* by default while the Shortcut for **view selected** is <kbd>NumpadPeriod</kbd>.

[image: 2.79 shortcuts]

In 2.8 they shortcuts are

- View Select <kbd>NumpadPeriod</kbd> (unchanged)
- Center View to Mouse <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd>

You can change the mapping in the User Preferences.

Comment: Am currently on my laptop and it seems like without a MMB and Numpad I have no way to view selected.

Comment: You can always change it in the User Preferences. That's where the screenshot is from.